# How to Select an Insert or Update into column within a defined value area

Tags: firebird

I have a column which holds different values, let's say it is a sub database within one column.

For example: value1:abc, value2:123, value3:xyz.

How can I read out single values using select and how can write them back?

For example I want to read out value2:123 and want to write back value2:789

The question is how would I define the Select and the Update Firebird SQL order.

Comment: Don't store multiple values in a single column - this violates the **first normal form** of database design! One column = one value - **always**.

Comment: Thats clear but its an ERP system where i cant chance anything and it has only one free field to use. I use an external DB to sync external data with it and i need to write several values back so they are even editable for the user which use it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it via an UDF.
I don't know which language you prefer - so this is an example in Delphi. You have to copy the library to firebird's udf-directory and declare the functions in your Database with

```
DECLARE EXTERNAL FUNCTION GETVALUE
    CSTRING(32767),
    CSTRING(32767)
RETURNS CSTRING(32767) FREE_IT
ENTRY_POINT 'GetValue' MODULE_NAME 'Project1';
DECLARE EXTERNAL FUNCTION SETVALUE
    CSTRING(32767),
    CSTRING(32767),
    CSTRING(32767)
RETURNS CSTRING(32767) FREE_IT
ENTRY_POINT 'SetValue' MODULE_NAME 'Project1';
```

Then can you use it in an SQL-Statement:

```
SELECT GETVALUE(valuescolumn, 'Value1') from valuestable;
```

or

```
UPDATE valuestable SET valuescolum = SETVALUE(valuescolumn, 'Value1', 'NewValue')
```

I wrote it down without testing it - so I'm not sure if I have any syntax error in it.

```
library Project1;

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes;

{$IFDEF ib_util}
function ib_util_malloc(l: integer): pointer; cdecl; external 'ib_util.dll';
{$ELSE}
function malloc(Bytes: Integer): Pointer; cdecl; external 'msvcrt.dll';
{$ENDIF}

function MemAlloc(Bytes: Integer): Pointer;
begin
{$IFDEF ib_util}
  Result:= ib_util_malloc(Bytes);
{$ELSE}
  Result:= malloc(Bytes);
{$ENDIF}
end;

function MakeResult(aString: string): PChar;
var
  fLength: Integer;
begin
  fLength:= Length(aString);
  Result:= MemAlloc(fLength+1);
  if fLength > 0 then
    Move(aString[1], Result[0], fLength);
  Result[fLength]:= #0;
end;

function GetValue(aValues, aValueName: PChar): PChar; cdecl; export;
var
  ValueList: TStringList;
  TempResult: string;
begin
  ValueList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    try
      ValueList.Text := aValues;
      ValueList.NameValueSeparator := ':';
      TempResult := ValueList.Values[aValueName];
      Result:= MakeResult(TempResult);
    except
      Result:= nil;
    end;
  finally
    ValueList.Free;
  end;
end;

function SetValue(aValues, aValueName, aValue: PChar): PChar; cdecl; export;
var
  ValueList: TStringList;
begin
  ValueList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    try
      ValueList.Text := aValues;
      ValueList.NameValueSeparator := ':';
      ValueList.Values[aValueName] := aValue;
      Result:= MakeResult(ValueList.Text);
    except
      Result:= nil;
    end;
  finally
    ValueList.Free;
  end;
end;

begin
end.
```